# Ansible. How to automate npm install

Tags: node.js, ansible, npm-install

I have some project on angular, which needed `npm install`.
Deps contain semantic-ui installation. When process progress I get message:

```
? Set-up Semantic UI (Use arrow keys)
❯ Automatic (Use defaults locations and all components) 
Express (Set components and output folder) 
Custom (Customize all src/dist values)
```

I should press `Ctrl+C` to continue installation with success, if i press something other, `npm install` without errors, but applications would not work. And i need to say that, after npm install I make `npm run prod` and that command doesn't finish successful, in case two.

How can I automate installation, how to emulate combination of `Ctrl+C` and use it with ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this problem, but in other way and bypassing ansible.
I took only exactly that libs, which  I need from semantic-ui